# Using conditional formatting to change format of row of cells based off multiple cells data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-formatting

[image: Excel sheet in question]

So I would like to set up a conditional formatting option to change the background of a row to dark grey once all three of the check marks shown in the picture are checked. I haven't been able to successfully do this yet. Here's a picture of what I would like the row to look like:

[image: Sheet with correct formatting]

Since the check boxes are tied to the cells they are in, I've tried using an AND function with the conditional formatting and set it for all the cells to read "TRUE" as the condition. This didn't end up working:

```
=AND($B$5="TRUE", $M$5="TRUE", $N$5="TRUE")
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible in Excel. Any ideas/suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: `=AND($B5, $M5, $N5)`

Comment: ^^^^^ `TRUE` is not equivalent to `"TRUE"`.

Comment: Thank you both! "=AND($B5, $M5, $N5)" worked for this.